# Error while composing Rust container: unrecognized command-line option '-m64'

Tags: docker, rust, openssl

I have the following project structure:

```
.
├── ./Cargo.lock
├── ./Cargo.toml
├── ./Dockerfile
├── ./Readme.md
├── ./docker-compose.yml
├── ./facade-service
│   ├── ./facade-service/Cargo.toml
│   └── ./facade-service/src
│       └── ./facade-service/src/main.rs
├── ./logging-service
│   ├── ./logging-service/Cargo.toml
│   └── ./logging-service/src
│       └── ./logging-service/src/main.rs
├── ./messages-service
│   ├── ./messages-service/Cargo.toml
│   └── ./messages-service/src
│       └── ./messages-service/src/main.rs
├── ./src
│   └── ./src/main.rs
```

...which is a cargo workspace with three members:

```ini
[workspace]
members = [
    "facade-service",
    "logging-service",
    "messages-service",
]
resolver = "2"
```

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM rust:1.75.0 as builder
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y pkg-config make g++ libssl-dev musl-tools
RUN apt update && apt -y upgrade

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY .. .

RUN rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
RUN cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --release

FROM rust:alpine3.19 as facade-service

RUN apk add --no-cache openssl-dev pkgconfig

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/facade-service /usr/local/bin/facade-service

CMD ["facade-service"]
```

...and docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  facade-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: facade-service
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

All of the workspace members compile during simple `cargo build` command.

But when I try doing `docker compose up`, I'm getting this mistake (at the step `cargo build`):

```
Configuring OpenSSL version 3.2.1 for target linux-x86_64
14.17   **********************************************************************
14.17   ***                                                                ***
14.17   ***   OpenSSL has been successfully configured                     ***
14.17   ***                                                                ***
14.17   ***   If you encounter a problem while building, please open an    ***
14.17   ***   issue on GitHub <https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues>  ***
14.17   ***   and include the output from the following command:           ***
14.17   ***                                                                ***
14.17   ***       perl configdata.pm --dump                                ***
14.17   ***                                                                ***
14.17   ***   (If you are new to OpenSSL, you might want to consult the    ***
14.17   ***   'Troubleshooting' section in the INSTALL.md file first)      ***
14.17   ***                                                                ***
14.17   **********************************************************************
14.17   running cd "/usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-2fcd72f0886f27e7/out/openssl-build/build/src" && "make" "depend"
14.17   running cd "/usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-2fcd72f0886f27e7/out/openssl-build/build/src" && MAKEFLAGS="-j --jobserver-fds=8,13 --jobserver-auth=8,13" "make" "build_libs"
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Iutil/perl" "-Mconfigdata" "-MOpenSSL::paramnames" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" crypto/params_idx.c.in > crypto/params_idx.c
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/crypto/bn_conf.h.in > include/crypto/bn_conf.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/crypto/dso_conf.h.in > include/crypto/dso_conf.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Iutil/perl" "-Mconfigdata" "-MOpenSSL::paramnames" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/internal/param_names.h.in > include/internal/param_names.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/asn1.h.in > include/openssl/asn1.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/asn1t.h.in > include/openssl/asn1t.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/bio.h.in > include/openssl/bio.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/cmp.h.in > include/openssl/cmp.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/cms.h.in > include/openssl/cms.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/conf.h.in > include/openssl/conf.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Iutil/perl" "-Mconfigdata" "-MOpenSSL::paramnames" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/core_names.h.in > include/openssl/core_names.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/crmf.h.in > include/openssl/crmf.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/crypto.h.in > include/openssl/crypto.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/ct.h.in > include/openssl/ct.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/err.h.in > include/openssl/err.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/ess.h.in > include/openssl/ess.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/fipskey.h.in > include/openssl/fipskey.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/lhash.h.in > include/openssl/lhash.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/ocsp.h.in > include/openssl/ocsp.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/opensslv.h.in > include/openssl/opensslv.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/pkcs12.h.in > include/openssl/pkcs12.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/pkcs7.h.in > include/openssl/pkcs7.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/safestack.h.in > include/openssl/safestack.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/srp.h.in > include/openssl/srp.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/ssl.h.in > include/openssl/ssl.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/ui.h.in > include/openssl/ui.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/x509.h.in > include/openssl/x509.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/x509_vfy.h.in > include/openssl/x509_vfy.h
14.17   /usr/bin/perl "-I." "-Mconfigdata" "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/x509v3.h.in > include/openssl/x509v3.h
14.17   make depend && make _build_libs
14.17   make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-2fcd72f0886f27e7/out/openssl-build/build/src'
14.17   make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-2fcd72f0886f27e7/out/openssl-build/build/src'
14.17   make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-2fcd72f0886f27e7/out/openssl-build/build/src'
14.17   musl-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -Iapps/include  -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -O3 -O2 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -m64 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-2fcd72f0886f27e7/out/openssl-build/install/lib/engines-3\"" -DMODULESDIR="\"/usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-2fcd72f0886f27e7/out/openssl-build/install/lib/ossl-modules\"" -DOPENSSL_BUILDING_OPENSSL -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_NO_SECURE_MEMORY -MMD -MF apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_libctx.d.tmp -MT apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_libctx.o -c -o apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_libctx.o apps/lib/app_libctx.c
14.17   make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-2fcd72f0886f27e7/out/openssl-build/build/src'
14.17 
14.17   --- stderr
14.17   cc1: error: unrecognized command-line option '-m64'
14.17   cc1: error: unrecognized command-line option '-m64'
14.17   make[1]: *** [Makefile:3771: apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_libctx.o] Error 1
14.17   make: *** [Makefile:2283: build_libs] Error 2
14.17   thread 'main' panicked at /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/openssl-src-300.2.3+3.2.1/src/lib.rs:611:9:
14.17 
14.17 
14.17 
14.17   Error building OpenSSL:
14.17       Command: cd "/usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-2fcd72f0886f27e7/out/openssl-build/build/src" && MAKEFLAGS="-j --jobserver-fds=8,13 --jobserver-auth=8,13" "make" "build_libs"
14.17       Exit status: exit status: 2
14.17 
14.17 
14.17       
14.17   note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
14.17 warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --release" did not complete successfully: exit code: 101
```

I spent previous 8 hours trying to understand what's going on, but I was not able to. Why do I get this result? How do I fix that?

Comment: What is the CPU arch of your host?

Comment: My processor is M2 Pro (arm64)